# Error: Exception in HostFunction: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libreanimated.so" not found

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I am receiving this error when building an Android application after upgrading my react native version from 0.67 to 0.69. Is there anyone who can help me with this problem?

> Error: Exception in HostFunction: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> dlopen failed: library "libreanimated.so" not found

Comment: If anyone can share react-native-reanimated node module folder for 0.69. That will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> First stop your metro bundler delete nodemodules
>
> add the follow line in android/build.gradle

```
  ext {
            ...
       
             kotlinVersion = "update kotlin Version" // 1..4.10
           
        }
```

> reIntall the nodemodules clean the gradlew

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

> and if you are using proguard rule then add this line

```
-keep class com.swmansion.reanimated.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.turbomodule.** { *; }
```

> hope so after implement this solution you can fix your bug